# How to setup a Xerox phaser 3020 laser printer on raspberrypi?

Tags: raspbian-buster, cups

I have a Xerox phaser 3020 laser printer and I want to set it up with my raspberrypi 3B running

```
$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.63-v7+ #1249 SMP Thu Aug 1 16:26:30 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Current situation:

[image: Current situation]

I have the [driver](https://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-3020/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB) from the manufacturer but the arm architecture support is kind of vague to me because they have something in `uld/arm` folder in the driver software but can't figure it out how or what to do with it as the `install.sh` script fails for the RPI but works ok on x86_64 based GNU/Linux systems(tested already). So far I have provided the 3020 models's ppd file existing in the `uld/noarch/share/ppd` and copied the `uld/arm/rastertospl` to `/usr/lib/cups/filter/` directory but what about the rest of the files in the `uld/arm/` folder?

```
$ ls
gettext  libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1  libscmssc.so  pstosecps  rastertospl  smfpnetdiscovery  usbresetter
```

because I am still getting the error in the ***test page*** saying

```
SPL ERROR - please use the proper driver
    POSITION : 0x0 (0)
    SYSTEM : h6fwsim/xl_op
    LINE : 217
    VERSION : SPL 5.90 05-15-2014
    ERROR CODE : 11-1113
```

And the cups [error log](https://pastebin.com/raw/82iL8QXP).